# cambiar el value de un option dentro de un array

Tags: php, html

Sucede que tengo un `array` con los siguientes datos:

```
$sistemas2 = array('BILLETERO', 'VIDEO', 'CONTROL DE ACCESO', 
'CONTROL DE ACCESO  VIDEO', 'ALARMA', 'ALARMA   VIDEO');
```

Y lo recorro dentro de un select para generar un `<option>` por cada dato que se encuentre de la siguiente manera:

```
foreach ($sistemas2 AS $valor2) { ?>
<option <?php if ($sistemas2 == $valor2){ 
?>selected <?php } 
?>> <?php  echo $valor2; ?>
</option> <?php                                    
}
}
?>
```

Lo que quiero es que cada option tenga un valor especifico diferente al que se muestra por el array, para realizar una consulta a la base de datos.
ejemplo:

```html
<option value="controles">BILLETERO</option>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asi lo uso yo, donde `$programa->get('id_facultad')` es el id de la facultad actual y `$row['id_facultad']` es el arreglo de facultades

```
$activo = ($programa->get('id_facultad') == $row['id_facultad']) ? "selected" : "";
echo "<option ".$activo ." value='".$row['id_facultad']."'>".$row['nombre_facultad']."</option>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrias hacerlo con un array asociativo asi:

```
$sistemas2 = array('controles'=>'BILLETERO', 'v'=>'VIDEO','c'=> 'CONTROL DE ACCESO', 'cv'=>'CONTROL DE ACCESO  VIDEO','a'=> 'ALARMA', 'av'=>'ALARMA   VIDEO');
```

y luego lo recorres asi:

```
foreach ($sistemas2 AS $key => $valor2) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $key.'"'; if ($sistemas2 == $valor2){ ?>selected <?php } ?>> <?php  echo 
    $valor2; ?></option> <?php                                    
    }
 }?>
```